# How to learn encryption type from a mail message?

Tags: gpg, thunderbird, pgp

I use Thunderbid, Enigmail, GnuPG and pinentry.

When I receive encrypted message, how I can determine which algorithm is used:

- for encryption
- for checksuming (SHA1 or not)
- for compression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a method *inside* thunderbird, but storing the message as a file and dropping to the shell will reveal the information you're looking for.

### Getting verbose

`gpg -vv` will output very verbose information on the input, including the information you're looking for.

### An Example

An example of the output can be generated by encrypting and signing a message to your own key:

```
echo 'foo' | gpg --recipient a4ff2279 --encrypt --sign | gpg -vv
```

The slightly stripped output (removing bulky parts not relevant to the question at all) looks like:

```
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid CC73B287A4388025
    data: [4095 bits]

[snip, gpg asking for passphrase]

gpg: public key encrypted data: good DEK
:encrypted data packet:
    length: unknown
    mdc_method: 2
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID A4388025, created 2014-03-26
      "Jens Erat (born 1988-01-19 in Stuttgart, Germany)"
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
:compressed packet: algo=2
:onepass_sig packet: keyid 8E78E44DFB1B55E9
    version 3, sigclass 0x00, digest 8, pubkey 1, last=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1418376556, name="",
    raw data: 4 bytes
gpg: original file name=''
foo
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 8E78E44DFB1B55E9
    version 4, created 1418376556, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 8, begin of digest 81 67
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2014-12-12)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 8E78E44DFB1B55E9)
    data: [4095 bits]
gpg: Signature made Fri Dec 12 10:29:16 2014 CET using RSA key ID FB1B55E9
gpg: using subkey FB1B55E9 instead of primary key A4FF2279
[snip, trust validation]
gpg: binary signature, digest algorithm SHA256
gpg: decryption okay
```

### Interpreting the Output

If GnuPG only prints algorithm IDs (like for the compression), these can be looked up in [RFC 4880, Section "Constants"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9). Specifically for this example, we will find use of following algorithms:

- AES256 for symmetric encryption
- MDC 2 means SHA1 for the Modification Detection Code, which is the only defined at this time
- Compression algorithm 2, resolving to ZLIB
- SHA256 for the signature